# How to make Height Auto on Colorbox?

Tags: jquery, height, colorbox

I'm using a jQuery plugin called ColorBox and basically it creates a jquery modal however the modal has a fixed size height of "500" and I want it to have a minimum height but also I have expending menus within the modal so I would like to to automatically expand.  How do I do this?

The code I currently have is:

```
$(".colorboxlink1").colorbox({
  opacity:"0.2",
  width:"450",
  height:"500",
  title:"To close this dialog click X icon at the right", 
  iframe:true
});
```

Iv tried deleting the Height from this and using CSS, but that didnt work.  Iv tried putting what I know of jquery in this line, but nothing seems to work, however I am pretty new to jQuery.  Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 22):

You can use this:

```
$('.colorboxlink1').colorbox({ 
    onComplete : function() { 
       $(this).colorbox.resize(); 
    }    
});
```

And this in your code after colorbox was initialized:

```
$.colorbox.resize();
```

Comment: That tries to work,  It seems to show only half of the modal window though.  I'll keep playing and see what I can edit.

Comment: Tried this as well and my colorbox resizes to 0px height

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation and I used a the setTimeout function to give some time for the colorbox to load then called the resize method.

I called the colorbox

```
var profileHeight=jQuery('#profile').height(); //Get the height of the container     
    setTimeout(function (){
       jQuery.colorbox({
           html:jQuery('#profile').html(),
           width:'50%',
           height:profileHeight, 
           opacity:0.5})}
        , 600);
//Wait 700ms then resize
setTimeout(function(){jQuery(this).colorbox.resize();},700);
```

That got me the functionality I needed. The modal window always resizes to the content of the container

Answer (score 0):

Using the current version of ColorBox, you can specify the maximal sizes in percents:

```
$(".colorboxlink1").colorbox({
    maxWidth: '95%',
    maxHeight: '95%'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event like this then call resize:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function() {
    $.colorbox.resize(); 
});
```

look for 'event hooks' to see what else you can bind to here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/